# Specific examples of "hard-to-factorize" numbers

Tags: number-theory, examples-counterexamples

I am playing with different factorization algorithms such as Pollard-Rho and Pollard-(p-1) or Quadratic Sieve. I would like to test these algorithms in some examples. I know I can multiply two large primes and use that, but some of these algorithms have different behavior depending on some properties of the primes involved so I am looking for "hard" cases.

The numbers of RSA challenge are way to big. I need examples around 64 bits.

[This](http://www.spoj.com/problems/FACT2/) problem is nice, but I can't get the specific numbers used.

**Question:** Is there a web page/online database I can use to benchmark factorization algorithms?

Comment: 64 bit numbers are rather small...

Comment: I am experimenting with Pollard's Rho algorithm and friends. These algorithms are useful in this range.